# once initialize or assignable Variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)btnFutApt:(UIButton *)sender {

   CGSize rec;
    rec.height = view.frame.size.height;

    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    CGRect newFrame ;
    NSLog(@"HEFU %f ", rec.height);

    if (sender.selected) {
        viewFuExtMain.hidden = TRUE;
        viewFuIntMain.hidden = true;
         newFrame = viewFutAptMain.frame;
        newFrame.size.height = 115  ;
        viewFutAptMain.frame = newFrame;


    }
    else {

        viewFuExtMain.hidden = FALSE;
        viewFuIntMain.hidden = FALSE;
        newFrame = viewFutAptMain.frame;
        newFrame.size.height =  rec.height;
        viewFuMain.frame = newFrame;



    }
     NSLog(@"HEFU %f", rec.height);
}
```

want a variable will store height and wont change at any cost ..

Answer (score 0):

> Write a Getter Method Initialize with your Stored Value. Try I mentioned Code Below

```
@property(nonAtomic, Strong, get) CGFloat *Height;
```

Comment: in init method you have to give the value